# How can I easily annotate callself with pgf-umlsd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

I want to draw a sequence diagram with `pgf-umlsd` package. I would like to make some annotations regarding the points in time and durations of certain calls and messages. This works well for calls and messages - but I cannot figure out how to mark the beginning- and end-points of self-calls (callself). Can someone tell me how I can "get" the these points?

Here is a MWE of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread{a}{A}
        \newinst{b}{B}
        
        % Annotating a message works
        \mess{a}{msg}{b}
        \node[anchor=east](t0)at(mess from){$t_0$};
        \node[anchor=west](t0)at(mess to){$t_1$};

        \postlevel % for better readability
        
        % Annotating a call works
        \begin{call}{a}{c()}{b}{rc} \end{call}
        \node[anchor=east]at(cf1){$t_2$};
        \node[anchor=west]at(ct1){$t_3$};
        \node[anchor=west]at(rt1){$t_4$};
        \node[anchor=east]at(rf1){$t_5$};
        \draw [decorate, 
            decoration = {brace,
            raise=13pt,
            amplitude=3pt}]%
            let
                \p1=(ct1),
                \p2=(rt1)
            in
                (\x2,\y1) -- (\p2)
            node[pos=0.5,right=13pt]{$\Delta t_{34}$};

        \postlevel % for better readability
        
        % Annotating a selfcall does not work :(
        \begin{callself}{a}{cs()}{rcs} \end{callself}
        % These are placed on the previous call annotations:
        % \node[anchor=east]at(cf1){$t_6$};
        % \node[anchor=west]at(ct1){$t_7$};
        % \node[anchor=west]at(rt1){$t_8$};
        % \node[anchor=east]at(rf1){$t_9$};
        % \draw [decorate, 
        %     decoration = {brace,
        %     raise=13pt,
        %     amplitude=3pt}]%
        %     let
        %         \p1=(ct1),
        %         \p2=(rt1)
        %     in
        %         (\x2,\y1) -- (\p2)
        %     node[pos=0.5,right=13pt]{$\Delta t_{69}$};
        
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

Results in the following (with annotations I would like to add crudely marked in red):
[image: Resulting PDF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! In order to get these coordinates, you have to dig into the source code of the package. Some coordinates don't even have names, so you need to do some shifting according to the defintions of the paths in the package.

The coordinate where you want to place "t_9" sits exactly at `([xshift=0.8cm, yshift=-0.33*\unitfactor cm]sce1)`. However, I changed the position of the label as well of the brace via additional shifting, because otherwise label and brace would overlap with the label for "rcs".

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread{a}{A}
        \newinst{b}{B}
        
        % Annotating a message works
        \mess{a}{msg}{b}
        \node[anchor=east](t0)at(mess from){$t_0$};
        \node[anchor=west](t0)at(mess to){$t_1$};

        \postlevel % for better readability
        
        % Annotating a call works
        \begin{call}{a}{c()}{b}{rc} \end{call}
        \node[anchor=east] at (cf1) {$t_2$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (ct1) {$t_3$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (rt1) {$t_4$};
        \node[anchor=east] at (rf1) {$t_5$};
        \draw [decorate, 
            decoration = {brace,
            raise=13pt,
            amplitude=3pt}]%
            let
                \p1=(ct1),
                \p2=(rt1)
            in
                (\x2,\y1) -- (\p2)
            node[pos=0.5,right=13pt]{$\Delta t_{34}$};

        \postlevel % for better readability
        
        \begin{callself}{a}{cs()}{rcs} \end{callself}
        \node[anchor=east] at (sc1) {$t_6$};
        \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=0.8cm]scb1) {$t_7$};
        \node[anchor=east] at (sct1){$t_8$};
        % coordinate for t9 is exactly at ([xshift=0.8cm, yshift=-0.33*\unitfactor cm]sce1)
        \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=0.8cm, yshift=-0.35cm]sce1) {$t_9$};
        \draw [decorate, 
             decoration = {brace,
             raise=13pt,
             amplitude=3pt}]%
             let
                 \p1=(sc1),
                 \p2=([xshift=1cm, yshift=-0.33*\unitfactor cm]sce1)
             in
                 (\x2,\y1) -- (\p2)
             node[pos=0.5,right=13pt]{$\Delta t_{69}$};

    \end{sequencediagram}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.

Leaves me wondering why the naming for selfcall-points is so different from call-points. I mean, sc makes sense, but why b/t/e? Could you point me to the file & line in the package where I can find the definition of these variables?

Also, this is kind of essential information missing in the documentation :(

Comment: @olpohl The defintions of `callanother` and `callself` are at line 128 and 159 of `pgf-umlsd.sty` respectively. I guess the author of this package did not think of this particular use case. It would be easy to add more coordinates into the path or change their names. You may want to write to the author (their contact data is also included in the `.sty` file).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into it and send the author a message.